# How to tell a program it's in a symlink folder?

Tags: symlink

If I have a symlink folder like:

`/home/user/foo/foo2 -> /home/user/bar/bar2`

I cd to: `/home/user/foo/foo2`.

If I do a `pwd`, it returns: `/home/user/foo/foo2`. Great!

But if I then `ls ../` it will return the contents of `/home/user/bar`.

Is there some way to make a program aware that it's in a symlink folder, so if it goes up a directory, it follows the reverse link?

Comment: As a workaround, you leverage the `cd ..` behavior in most modern shells to get what you want; define `function .. {
(cd ..;pwd)
 }` and then do things like `ls $(..)`

Comment: Relevant:  https://superuser.com/questions/1217237/why-does-ls-show-real-parent-content-when-im-inside-a-symbolic-link-direct

Comment: Depending on your actual use case, `ls "${PWD%/*}"` may be of help (assuming your shell doesn't change it to the physical path). Given that `foo2` is a symlink, "one level up from the specified path" seems more accurate, as a description of what you are looking for, than "the parent of the current directory".

Comment: This is a difficult problem, see https://9p.io/sys/doc/lexnames.html for how a different OS solves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, no. You’re not in foo2. That’s an illusion. Your shell keeps the illusion, that’s why it can see it. But any sub process doesn’t know about it

I’d check the $PWD env variable. See if your shell sets that to the illusion and sub processes can see it. But that’s only going to work in code you control. You know you check $PWD. Other apps will do (in effect ) call cwd().

Answer (score 0):

you can check if current output of `pwd` is a symlink. you can do it by using utilities like `file` or `stat`:

```
user@host:~/tmp$ mkdir -p sym/bar/bar
user@host:~/tmp$ mkdir -p sym/foo
user@host:~/tmp$ cd sym/foo/
user@host:~/tmp/sym/foo$ ln -s ../bar/bar/ ./foo
user@host:~/tmp/sym/foo$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 11 Feb 24 17:33 foo -> ../bar/bar/
user@host:~/tmp/sym/foo$ cd foo
user@host:~/tmp/sym/foo/foo$ pwd
/home/user/tmp/sym/foo/foo
user@host:~/tmp/sym/foo/foo$ file $(pwd)
/home/user/tmp/sym/foo/foo: symbolic link to ../bar/bar/
user@host:~/tmp/sym/foo/foo$ stat -c %F  $(pwd)
symbolic link
```